# Google Cloud Storage php glob() function

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am using a php app engine program, and am trying to use the `glob()` function. What I have is:

```
$files = glob("*.m4v");
foreach($files as $filename){
    $info = $info . $filename;
}
```

However the array is empty and returns nothing. How do you use `glob()` in Google Cloud Storage? It says `glob()` is supported..

Comment: you may need to add the directory path

Comment: looks like it was a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10623

Comment: i added a directory path, such as $path = "gs://bucket/$timeParam/$locationParam/truebase/"; but the same outcome occurs

Comment: visit this link for more information about reading and writing files on Cloud storage: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/